# Launching alert dialog some times work and some time it does not

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i'm using below code to launch the alert dialog. This works well sometimes & some times it does not.

` Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

```
      alarmIntent.setClass(ct, AlertsDlgactivity.class);
      alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Pass on the alarm ID as extra data
        // Start the popup activity
      ct.startActivity(alarmIntent);`
```

Also, few times multiple instances of dialog appears, any help on how to work on this

Comment: Why are you starting the activity as a new task? What happens when it does not "work well"?

Comment: You don't ever need another activity to show alerts.

Comment: But, it should show as alert dialog once notification occurs, like once alarm triggers. Here i'm clearing the AlertDialog object in oncreate & showing content.

Comment: @TedHopp, it does not launch the alert dialog even if all lines gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code, I'm not sure how your trying to accomplish this, so I am providing a simple Function to use the Alarm Manager:

```js
public void scheduleAlarm(int year,int month,int day,int hr,int min,int sec, String message, int _id)
    {
        long future = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day,hr,min,sec).getTimeInMillis();
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        intentAlarm.putExtra("_MESSAGE",message);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, future,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And this would be AlarmReciever.class

```js
public class AlarmReciever  extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Use this to get variables passed from Main Activity  
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("_MESSAGE");
        
        //Do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add these to your Manifest:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<application
             <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>

</application>
```